# Python SSH Based Web-based Remote directory/File viewer

Tags: python, linux, ssh

Is there a Python & SSH based web-based remove directory/file viewer out there?

Specifically, I want to be able to (over the web) browse directories, view, & download files (logs) from remote machines (authenticating via SSH).

Comment: Python based *and* ssh based *and* web based? Isn't that a bit contradictory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web-based web client will have to use some sort of framework. The most popular one that uses Python is Django. From there, you can use an available SSH library like Paramiko: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko

I don't know of an out-of-the-box solution for a Django-based SSH client so you would probably have to build the frontend for your client yourself.